# Why my code crashes after processing 29 files? (C Programming)

Tags: c, linux, file, gcc, file-management

I don' know what is going on. First 29 files were renamed as expected but on every time code crashes on twenty-ninth file. Could you help  my solve my problem

I use v12.2.0-gcc and run Arch Linux on a laptot.

Function that i'm working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int renameFiles(char *files[], char *path, char *prefix) {

  int i = 0;
  FILE *f;
  char *filename;
  char *ext;
  char *buffer;
  long numbytes;

  while ( files[i] != NULL ){

    filename = files[i];

    char filepath[sizeof path + sizeof filename];
    strcpy(filepath, path);
    strcat(filepath, filename);

    f = fopen(filepath, "rb");

    if (f == NULL)
      return 1;

    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    numbytes = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    buffer = (char*)calloc(numbytes, sizeof(char*));

    if (buffer == NULL)
      return 1;

    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), numbytes, f);
    fclose(f);


    remove(filepath);

    ext = strrchr(filename, '.');

    if (!ext)
      ext = "";

    char int_str[sizeof i];
    sprintf(int_str, "%d", i + 1);

    char newfilename[sizeof prefix + sizeof int_str + sizeof ext];
    strcpy(newfilename, prefix);
    strcat(newfilename, int_str);
    strcat(newfilename, ext);

    char newfilepath[sizeof path + sizeof newfilename];
    strcpy(newfilepath, path);
    strcat(newfilepath, newfilename);


    f = fopen(newfilepath, "w");

    if (f == NULL)
      return 1;

    fwrite(buffer, 1, numbytes, f);
    printf("%s\n", newfilepath);
    fclose(f);

    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Main.c

```
#include "files.h"
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char *files[1024] = {};
  getFilesList(files, argv[1]);

  int length = 0;

  while( files[length] != NULL ){
    length++;
  }

  printf("%d files found on %s\n", length + 1, argv[1]);


  char *userInput = readline("Continue (y/n): ");

  if (strcmp(userInput, "y") != 0){
    return 0;
  }

  renameFiles(files, argv[1], argv[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

I was making code for commandline/terminal application that cloud get directory and renamed them with prefix and to number like (bg.jpeg, image.jpg, wallpaper.png) to (file-1.jpeg, file-2.jpg, file-3.png....) while keeping to file extension as same. My code works for smaller ammunt of files but when file amount goes above 29 it crashes on the end.

Comment: `char filepath[sizeof path + sizeof filename];` won't work for two reasons: The first is that the size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to (which really is just a single value, a single `char` in your case). Use `strlen` to get the length of a string. Secondly, you forget space for the null-terminator.

Comment: you should print out all the `sizeof` values.  They are likely way off what you are expecting.   Also, you are not [renaming](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rename) anything.  You are copying.

Comment: `calloc(numbytes, sizeof(char*))` is also wrong, but in the "good" way that you allocate *more* memory than needed. Four or eight times more than needed.

Comment: More array and allocation problems: `char int_str[sizeof i];` which will allocate a string with space for only three characters (assuming the common size of `4` for `int`), plus the string null-terminator.

Comment: All in all, it seems you have skipped some very important parts of your learning material, and you need to go back and refresh some of the array and pointer basics.

Comment: I see you using `sprintf` to convert an integer to string.  That can also be used to clean up the `strcpy` + `strcat` stuff.